# Two discrete ranges when using cv2.inRange

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I am trying to detect different color ranges in an image using python in hsv color space.
One problem with the red color is that the range is not continuous.

```
lower_red = np.array([0,100,100])
upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])
lower_red2 = np.array([161,100,100])
upper_red2 = np.array([179, 255, 255])
```

So I have to use `mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask_1, mask_2)`

I use a for loop to iterate a list red color is the only exception in the list. So I hard code when finding the mask of the red color but the code is ugly. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

```
  if i != 3 and i != 4:
    mask = cv2.inRange (img_hsv, colours[i][0], colours[i][1])
  elif i == 3: # Red color 
    mask_1 = cv2.inRange (img_hsv, colours[3][0], colours[3][1])
    mask_2 = cv2.inRange (img_hsv, colours[4][0], colours[4][1])
    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask_1, mask_2)
  else: 
    continue
```

this is the original code

```
img = ori_img.copy()
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # Convert BGR to HSV

# define range of colors in HSV
lower_blue = np.array([120, 50, 20])
upper_blue = np.array([158, 255, 255])
lower_green = np.array([25,52,70])
upper_green = np.array([102,255,255])
lower_yellow = np.array([20,100,100])
upper_yellow = np.array([30,255,255])

lower_red = np.array([0,100,100])
upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])
lower_red2 = np.array([161,100,100])
upper_red2 = np.array([179, 255, 255])

lower_black = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper_black = np.array([179, 255, 72])

colours = np.array([[lower_blue,upper_blue],
                    [lower_green,upper_green],
                    [lower_yellow,upper_yellow],
                    [lower_red,upper_red],
                    [lower_red2,upper_red2], 
                    [lower_black,upper_black]])

for i in range(int(colours.size/6)):
  if i != 3 and i != 4:
    mask = cv2.inRange (img_hsv, colours[i][0], colours[i][1])
  elif i == 3: # Red color 
    mask_1 = cv2.inRange (img_hsv, colours[3][0], colours[3][1])
    mask_2 = cv2.inRange (img_hsv, colours[4][0], colours[4][1])
    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask_1, mask_2)
  else: 
    continue    

  # Find contours and filter using threshold area
  colourcnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2] 

  if len(colourcnts)>0:
          coloured_cnt = max(colourcnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
  cntArea = cv2.contourArea(coloured_cnt)
  if cntArea > 400: 
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(coloured_cnt) # offsets - with this you get 'mask'
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

imshow(img)
```

Comment: lift the special case into a general case. `colors = [[blue1], [green1], [yellow1], [red1, red2]]`, see? -- if you have trouble with near-black getting outrageous saturation values, try both HSL and HSV. one of them handles that better than the other.

Comment: If you invert your image, red becomes cyan, which is in a contiguous area on the HSV colourwheel. So you could search for cyan in an inverted copy of your image.